# Win Batch nested for returns "unexpected" error

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, indexing, nested, delay

Win10, CMD.

Working on a long, complicated script, and hit a part that just does not want to cooperate.  Here's a snippet that illustrates the problem:

```
set TESTSTR="abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz"
for /l %%a in (1,1,9) do (
    set I=%%a
    for /f "tokens=!I!" %%b in ("%TESTSTR%") do echo %%b
)
```

The expected result would be

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
vwx
yz
```

But I just get 9x of this:

```
!I!" was unexpected at this time.
```

I've tried multiple variants of this, including set VAR="tokens=%%a" - for /f !VAR! ...  I've stuck various echos in there and found that the variable %%a is incrementing properly and any intermediate vars I try to use are being set correctly.

It just doesn't seem to be able to use a delayed expansion or loop variable in the options section of another loop.  I've done similar pre-loop options definitions and they normally work just fine, but never tried it in nested for's, using the outside loop's variable as a parameter for the inside loop like this.

Example: this code snippet works, showing only directories named "Update??" in the current dir (yes, I know that's way more than would be needed, I just grabbed it and repurposed it for this demo - the original code had a set rather than echo, with the intent of grabbing the most recent directory):

```
    set FORPARM="usebackq tokens=1"
    for /f %FORPARM% %%f in (`dir /b /a:d /o:d Update??`) do echo %%f
```

This example is not inside a for or other situation that would require delayed expansion, which I think is causing issues with the problem code above - the for command just doesn't seem to be able to handle delayed expansion or for variables as part of its command.

I suppose I could do it with call, putting the first for's var as a parameter to the call, and the call has the inner for, but would prefer not to - the routine I pulled this from is complex enough already - it reads a data file and populates multiple arrays.  I have a variant of that routine that works, but it's pretty kludgey & requires editing when the number of arrays changes in the data file. I'm trying to speed it up, make it neater, and not require code alteration when the data alters.

Anyone else ever seen and gotten past this one?

Comment: Not understanding why you just wouldn't do this: `set "TESTSTR=abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz"` and a simple `FOR` command. `FOR %%G IN (%TESTSTR%) DO ECHO %%G`.

Comment: @Squashman Because the above is an example to illustrate the problem.  The actual code has a lot more instead of that inner for's `echo`, and there's more inside the outer loop than the inner `for`.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close with your code.
The inner for-loop needs the updated value from the outer for-loop in it's for parameter.
This can be done by moving the inner for-loop to a subroutine and call this subroutine.
In the code below I have changed the inner for-loop to a single-line subroutine.
This keeps the code very close to yours.

```
@echo off
set TESTSTR="abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz"
for /l %%a in (1,1,9) do (
    cmd/c "@echo off&for /f "tokens=%%a" %%b in (%TESTSTR%) do echo %%b"
)
```

Comment: Yes, I know I could do this, though I'd have to do a call inside the same script rather than a single-command `cmd/c` - as I told @Squashman above, the code snippet above only illustrates the issue - the actual code has a lot more to it.  I was hoping to avoid using these methods, as that section is complex enough already.  I guess if I must, I must...  Thanks for confirming that!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really consider this THE answer, but it is AN answer, based on what I was trying to avoid (and @OJBakker's answer).  Putting this here instead of a comment because the comment just munges the code sections - I probably just don't know what I'm doing there yet...)

With the code as:

```
:nested_for_test
    set TESTSTR=abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
    for /l %%a in (1,1,9) do (
        call :nested_for_test_inner %%a
    )
    exit /b
:nested_for_test_inner
    for /f "tokens=%1" %%b in ("%TESTSTR%") do (
        echo %%b
    )
    exit /b
```

Yes, I know the "do" sections do not need to be parenthecated - they are that way because the "real" code has a lot more than just a single line in each do...

The results are as expected:

```
Start:  8:28:05.98
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
vwx
yz
Start:  8:28:05.98
Stop:  8:28:07.76
Elapsed: 1.78 seconds
```

Yes, I have a timer routine in my test file. This shows slower than I'd hoped, but within reason, considering the extra call.

If someone figures out how to do it without that call, please add!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** completely changed due to new information.

Please try this new code. I guess it won't get much faster using batch.
As `%_VAR%` isn't used, you could simplify your second parameter (and skip disassembling `%_COND%`)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=%~1"
set "_COND=%~2"
if not defined file goto :eof

for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ("%_COND%") do ( 
  set "_VAR=%%a"
  set "_VAL=%%b"
)
rem set _
echo Start: %time%
REM get field names:
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr /b "arry " "%file%"') do (
  set cnt=-1
  for %%C in (%%B) do (
    set /a cnt+=1
    set "%%A[!cnt!]=%%C"
  )
)

REM get Data-Array:
set "cnt=0"  & REM number of data sets 
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr /brc:"data .*%_VAL%\>" %file%') do (
  set /a cnt+=1
  set "cnt2=-1"  & REM number of entries in the dataset
  for %%C in (%%B) do (
    set /a cnt2+=1
    call set "%%arry[!cnt2!]%%[!cnt!]=%%C"
    call set /a %%arry[!cnt2!]%%[0]=cnt 
  )

)
echo End: %time%
set |find "["
echo there are entries 0 to %cnt%.
```

Things that speed it up:

- filtering the input (less lines to process)
- no `IF`'s at all
- works even with empty `%_VAL%` so no need to check it each iteration of the loop

Possible contras:

- filterstring is case sensitive (can be changed with `findstr`'s  `/i` parameter, but would also make the keyword `data`  case insensitive.
- Possibly false positives (John / Johnson is no probem because of the word-boundary `\>`, but `JohnJohn` would be found with the `John` filter (`Johnjohn` wouldn't))
- I very much hope the 5-token datasets and the 7-token datasets are in different files

There is no hardcoded limit for the tokens of the dataset.

Runtimes with your example file: 200ms with filter, 260 ms without. Thanks to the filtering, a filtered list is even faster than the unfiltered.

Comment: Wow.  Works nicely.  There are a couple things I don't understand about it, and one thing I need to change (and can't because I don't understand some of it?).
- First, the 7 and 5 token datasets are different.  Both are used in the same code, but the datasets live in different files. Some things...
- the `set "file=%~1"` - why the tilde?
- Right, VAR not used - removed that line; is now a single line `for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ("%_COND%") do set "_VAL=%%b" ` )  Might remove the `VAR:` part completely, but that's a bit of doing in the main code, so that's for later

Comment: (continued)
- not worried about the filter matching issues you mentioned. Due to the nature of the real data, it won't be an issue
- does `rem set _` actually do something?
- the `findstr` does not work at the command line, but does in the batch. this is odd - do you know why?
- I changed all instances of `cnt` to `IDX` (just my style, and what my eyes are used to looking for
- I do not understand the `call` line.  I do get the delayed expansion parts and the `%%C` - Break the rest down?

Comment: (continued)
- The program which this is part of expects to find the upper boundary (`cnt`) in each array's [0] element.  Moving the data from 0-to-(cnt-1) to 1-to-cnt is simple enough, but since I don't get the call line, I don't see how to set the [0] element as I need it.  Perhaps something like `for /l %%X in (0,1,%IDX2%) do call set "%%arry[%%x][0]=%IDX%"` after the `call set`'s `for` loop ends? I've played with variants of this and can't seem to hit it...

Comment: in case you're curious, I'm getting times of 2.21 to 2.37 seconds for unfiltered (103 lines) read of the 7-element dataset, and 1.88 to 2.09 sec for filtered (83 lines)..   The 5-element set has times of 1.04 to 1.65 unfiltered (19 lines) and 0.85 to 1.2 sec filtered (7 lines).

Comment: it's just a matter of where to start the counters. See my edited code. I'll answer your other questions tomorrow - I'm a bit short of time right now.

Comment: No worries. I noted two things.  The setting of `[0]` inside that loop slowed it down (taking half-again as long), so I moved that `set` into its own loop after the data read. Much faster.  Second, the last field can' be used for filtering unless the data lines include a space after them. No worries there, as my real data is filtered on fields in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Okay... To clarify the issue.  Here's the original "kludgey" code - actual code, not a simplified illustrative sample (I left my comments to explain what it's doing):

```
:: 'call :array_load pathname [arry:val]'
::  INPUT - 1-2 parameters: datafile path and optional condition
::  RESULT - sets up arrays & UBOUNDs (array[0])
:: Read a datafile (identified in the first parameter). This file has an array
:: definition line and a number of data lines. The array definition line starts
:: with 'arry ' and lists the arrays to be populated from the data statements.
:: Data statements list the information to be put into the arrays, in the same
:: order as the arrays listed in the arry statement.
:: An optional second parameter causes only lines that have the value given for
:: that array to be included (ex: 'ZIP:23456' causes only addresses in zipcode
:: 23456 to be read).
:: The arry statement can be anywhere in the file. The data statements are read
:: in the order of appearance.
:: The Upper boundary (UBOUND) is stored in [0]
:array_load
    set _DATAFILE=%1
    set _COND=%2
    if not exist %_DATAFILE% (
        echo [E] - {array_load} Array datafile %1 not found.  Aborting run.
        pause
        exit
    )
:: Detect and set up for use of the second parameter.
    if defined _COND for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ("%_COND%") do (set _ARY=%%a&set _VAL=%%b)
:: Gets the list of arrays from the "arry" statement
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in (`findstr "^arry " %_DATAFILE%`) do ( set "ARRAYLIST=%%b")
:: Set up the array names and prep for the second loop. The "tokens" var sets
:: up to read the columns in the data statements. Token 1 is always "data" and
:: is skipped.
    set ndx=1
    for %%a in (%ARRAYLIST%) do (
        set COL!ndx!=%%a
        set /a ndx+=1
    )
:: "TOKENS" is not a mathematical calculation - it is a range definition used
:: in the next FOR statement. Do not add /a to the set!
    set TOKENS=2-%ndx%
    set /a ARYCOUNT=ndx-1
:: Read the data statements into the arrays. The "if defined" increments the
:: index for the next read only if there is no condition or the condition is
:: met. The "for" inside this "if" exists because the condition can't be tested
:: without it.
    set ndx=1
    for /f "usebackq tokens=%TOKENS%" %%a in (`findstr "^data " %_DATAFILE%`) do (
        set !COL1![!ndx!]=%%a
        if %ARYCOUNT% GEQ 2 set !COL2![!ndx!]=%%b
        if %ARYCOUNT% GEQ 3 set !COL3![!ndx!]=%%c
        if %ARYCOUNT% GEQ 4 set !COL4![!ndx!]=%%d
        if %ARYCOUNT% GEQ 5 set !COL5![!ndx!]=%%e
        if %ARYCOUNT% GEQ 6 set !COL6![!ndx!]=%%f
        if %ARYCOUNT% GEQ 7 set !COL7![!ndx!]=%%g
        if defined _COND (
            for /f "usebackq" %%x in (`echo %_ARY%[!ndx!]`) do set RES=!%%x!
            if !RES!==%_VAL% set /a ndx+=1
        ) else (
            set /a ndx+=1
        )
        set /a !COL1![0]=!ndx!-1
        if %ARYCOUNT% GEQ 2 set /a !COL2![0]=!ndx!-1
        if %ARYCOUNT% GEQ 3 set /a !COL3![0]=!ndx!-1
        if %ARYCOUNT% GEQ 4 set /a !COL4![0]=!ndx!-1
        if %ARYCOUNT% GEQ 5 set /a !COL5![0]=!ndx!-1
        if %ARYCOUNT% GEQ 6 set /a !COL6![0]=!ndx!-1
        if %ARYCOUNT% GEQ 7 set /a !COL7![0]=!ndx!-1
    )
    exit /b
```

This routine loads a set of index-correlated arrays.  Here's an example data file.  I left the comments in the file to help explain what's going on.  Only the "arry" and "data" lines are actually used by the routine.

```
To be REFERENCED by :array_load function

The line starting with "arry " contains the names of the arrays to be
filled from the data provided. Columns do not need to line up; extra spaces
are ignored. There is a maximum of six arrays without revisiting the
:array_load functions. ANY change of the "arry" names requires revisiting
the code that uses them!

All Data lines must begin with "data ", and NO other lines can start that
way! The keywords "data" and "arry" are case-sensitive and must be followed
by a space.

All lines that do NOT start with "arry " or "data " are comments.

arry FIRST   LAST    PHONE        ZIP

data Joe     Wilson  202-417-2742 20122
data John    Doe     209-659-2482 10523
data Susan   Doe     209-659-2482 10523
data Bill    Johnson 619-384-2582 53737
data Cindy   Wahler  301-724-7496 20933
data Rebecca Tannis  410-473-2748 20536

This will result in FIRST[0]=6, FIRST[1]=Joe, LAST[0]=6, LAST[1]=Wilson, etc
on up to FIRST[6]=Rebecca ... ZIP[6]=20536  (all the [0]'s = 6, as the array size)
```

The code above works (and is **reasonably** fast), unless the last line is excluded by the condition check, in which case the last line is not actually excluded.  It also must be edited if the number of arrays exceed the number of if ... geq .. %%... statements.

I'd like to: 1) fix the last line exclusion bug, 2) remove the many IFs for array count flexibility, 3) make it faster.

This is what I'm tinkering with now.  It does #2, I expect it to do #1 when I get that part worked out, but it fails miserably on #3 - FAR slower.  On this computer, it takes 20-30 seconds to process this list of just 6 values for only 4 arrays - my actual data files are about 110 lines with 7 values each and 21 lines of 5 each.

```
:array_load
    set _DATAFILE=%1
    set _FILTER=
    if not exist %_DATAFILE% (
        echo [E] - {array_load} Array datafile %1 not found.  Aborting run.
        pause
        exit /b
    )
    if not "%2"=="" set _FILTER=%2
:: Gets the list of arrays from the "arry" statement
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in (`findstr "^arry " %_DATAFILE%`) do ( set "ARRAYLIST=%%b")
:: Set up the array names and prep for the second loop.
    set ndx=1
    for %%a in (%ARRAYLIST%) do (
        set COL[!ndx!]=%%a
        set /a ndx+=1
    )
    set /a ARYCNT=ndx-=1
:: Token 1 is always "data" and is skipped.
    set ndx=1
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in (`findstr "^data " %_DATAFILE%`) do (
        set _LN=%%b
        for /l %%x in (1,1,%ARYCNT%) do (
            set ARY=!COL[%%x]!
            call :array_load_inner %%x
        )
        set /a ndx+=1
    )
    exit /b
:array_load_inner
    for /f "tokens=%1" %%z in ("!_LN!") do set !ARY![!ndx!]=%%z
    set /a !ARY![0]=!ndx!
    exit /b
```

So, does this make your eyes cross as it does mine? :)

Either routine above is an "answer", just not the one I'm after - the first is my starting point, and works to the extent of the original question, which did not include references to arrays or inclusions. The second is far too slow to be viable. @Stephan answer would work if I weren't dealing with arrays. Apologies for putting this material into an "Answer" block - it's far too large for a comment (I guess I should have included original full code from the beginning, rather than try to keep the sample code at the "smallest common denominator", so to speak).  Sorry...

Comment: Hm - are you aware that `Mary Lou Jones` will kill your script? (in other words: that no data element is allowed to include a space)

Comment: @Stephan - Yes, I know.  If this were real data, she would be `MaryLou Jones` or just `Mary Jones`.  My real data does not face that problem, and, by its nature, never will.

Comment: Easiest and by far fastest solution would be to filter the data in the first place: (`findstr "^data\ .*<%_VAL_%>" "%_DATAFILE%"` (see `findstr /?` for `\<` and `\>)`), but I don't know if that's safe enough with your data. It might give false positives, when `%_VAL%` occurs in other fields (think of names that might be first or second names).

Comment: @Stephan - that would actually work... Wow, mental blind spot! The actual data is not subject to the first/last issue you mentioned (all fields are unique styles/patterns). Nor do I really need to care where on the line the filter criteria appears - they're unique.  Playing with this at the command line, I couldn't get it to work - I'd either get everything - including comments or not - or nothing.  I changed it a little: `findstr "^data " %_DATAFILE% | findstr %_VAL%` which worked as expected.  Just set _VAL=data when no criteria is used, to make sure the second `findstr` gets them all.

Comment: @Stephan - works well (had to put a ^" in front of the pipe to make it work in a batch rather than commandline).  The sample data still takes 2.2 seconds to load with the ZIP:10523 filter and almost 5 seconds unfiltered. My larger data file takes over 2 min to read unfiltered, abt 100 sec with a filter that took about 3/4 of the data. The main slowdown is elsewhere, so #1 is handled, but can't seem to get both #2 and #3 (no multi-if and speed).

Comment: try `findstr /brc:"data .*%_val%\>" datafile.txt`. No piping means, it's faster.

Comment: @Stephan - failed.  Tried with `/b`, `/br` as well (aren't `/r` and `/c` mutually exclusive?)   Anyway, the original code (multiple `if`) with the `findstr` in the `for` parameter, works well and is fast. Takes .90 or less to read the large dataset without filtering and .95 or less with it (less than .05sec difference)...   Now if I could just get rid of the multiple `if` section, that chunk of code would no longer be an eyesore.

Comment: It's `/L` /(**L**iteral) and `/R` (**R**egex), which are mutually exclusive. Have you noticed my changed answer?